# How do I move input columns in a shiny app to the right of existing columns?

Tags: r, shiny

There's a wrinkle here to my code that prevents me from using the more common form of utilizing multiple columns. Here's a basic reproduction of my code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(id = "one",
    column(12,
           numericInput("age1", label = "Age 1", value = 30, min = 18),
           numericInput("hgt1", label = "Height 1", value = 172, min = 0))
  ),
  fluidRow(id = "two",
    column(12,
           numericInput("age2", label = "Age 2", value = 30, min = 18),
           numericInput("hgt2", label = "Height 2", value = 172, min = 0))
  ),
  fluidRow(column(12,
                  numericInput("x1", label = "Variable 1", value = 50, min = 0),
                  numericInput("x2", label = "Variable 2", value = 100, min = 0))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

My primary goal is that I want the

```
fluidRow(column(12,
                  numericInput("x1", label = "Variable 1", value = 50, min = 0),
                  numericInput("x2", label = "Variable 2", value = 100, min = 0))
)
```

portion of the code to display the inputs to the RIGHT of the inputs above, not UNDERNEATH them like they are now. I want two columns for inputs on my UI: one for the age / height information, and another for these two additional variables.

I cannot use something like

```
fluidRow(id = "one",
  column(6,
         numericInput("age1", label = "Age 1", value = 30, min = 18),
         numericInput("hgt1", label = "Height 1", value = 172, min = 0)
  ),
  column(6,
         numericInput("x1", label = "Variable 1", value = 50, min = 0),
         numericInput("x2", label = "Variable 2", value = 100, min = 0)
  )
)
```

because that then ties the id of "one" to the Age 1 / Height 1 inputs, AND the Variable 1 and Variable 2 inputs. I want to be able to utilize this id to make that input disappear if needed, but I need the Variable 1 and Variable 2 inputs to display at all times and have no connection to the "one" id at all.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Use `div(id="one1", numericInput()` to define within a `column(6,...)` and make it hide or show (could use `shinyjs()`).  No need to depend on the fluidRow id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`column(width=12, ...)` is always going to take full-width. I think you need:

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  column(6, 
    fluidRow(id = "one",
             numericInput("age1", label = "Age 1", value = 30, min = 18),
             numericInput("hgt1", label = "Height 1", value = 172, min = 0)),
    fluidRow(id = "two",
             numericInput("age2", label = "Age 2", value = 30, min = 18),
             numericInput("hgt2", label = "Height 2", value = 172, min = 0))
  ),
  column(6,
    fluidRow(numericInput("x1", label = "Variable 1", value = 50, min = 0),
             numericInput("x2", label = "Variable 2", value = 100, min = 0))
  )
)
```

[image: firefox with side-by-side groups of variables]